# Is quantum mechanics only applied to particle having mass?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I was reading Wikipedia article on Quantum Field Theory. It is written that Quantum mechanics cannot give an account for photon.

Comment: "Ordinarily, quantum mechanics (QM) cannot give an account of photons which constitute the prime case of relativistic 'particles'. Since photons have rest mass zero, and correspondingly travel in the vacuum at the speed c, a non-relativistic theory such as ordinary QM cannot give even an approximate description. Photons are implicit in the emission and absorption processes which have to be postulated; for instance, when one of an atom's electrons makes a transition between energy levels. The formalism of QFT is needed for an explicit description of photons."

Comment: What is the confusion here? Have you read carefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article says:

> Ordinarily, quantum mechanics (QM) cannot give an account of photons which constitute the prime case of relativistic 'particles'. Since photons have rest mass zero, and correspondingly travel in the vacuum at the speed $c$, a non-relativistic theory such as ordinary QM cannot give even an approximate description.

This isn't well phrased. By *quantum mechanics* the article presumably means the form of the [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) originally written down by Schrödinger in 1925. This is a non-relativistic equation so it can describe only particles moving at velocities that are small compared to the speed of light. Since photons move at the speed of light (obviously) they can't be described by a non-relativistic equation.

However we can formulate quantum mechanics so it can describe relativistic particles and the result is normally called [relativistic quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_mechanics). So it isn't really fair to say that quantum mechanics cannot describe relativistic particles.

However relativistic quantum mechanics has some limitations, and it isn't until we move to quantum field theory that we get a really good description of relativistic (as well as non-relativistic) particles.

You ask:

> Is quantum mechanics only applied to particle having mass?

but non-relativistic quantum mechanics will fail even for particles with mass if those particles are travelling at speeds near $c$. For example the Schrodinger equation is unable to describe what happens when particles collide in the LHC. It isn't a question of whether the particles are massive or not, but whether they are relativistic or not.

Comment: To clear up last paragraph further, OP should note that massless particles travel at the speed of light, and so, are always relativistic. Therefore, non-relativistic quantum mechanics cannot be used there.

Comment: "The Schrödinger equation" is valid in all of quantum mechanics and quantum field theory. It's the choice of Hamiltonian that distinguishes relativistic from non-relativistic mechanics, not the use of the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: I think it is also important to note that there are some really big no-go results that suggest that relativistic quantum mechanics is doomed a priori (and QFT is really needed; though QFT famously has its own problems).